# keep Mathematica session alive on ssh

Tags: kernel

I have to access to a server via ssh and open a graphical session, using XQuartz, for using  Mathematica. Is it possible to let Mathematica run even when I disconnect to the server?

I could add NotebookSave[] at the end of my program for saving the file, but I have no idea how to keep the evaluation running. I tried screen and tmux but maybe I hadn't set them properly and when I log out the calculations stop.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Do you need the graphical front end? If not consider running a mathematica kernel in script mode. (This can be started through ssh, and keeps running locally)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will definitely try it.  However it would be great to understand whether a GUI session can be kept alive

Comment: To keep a GUI session alive, you actually need a setup that keeps the graphical interface on the server alive. The best way to do this is to have a remote desktop setup (e.g. using x2go or something similar). However, this may not been an option If you are connecting to a computer cluster or something.

Comment: How about using nohup?